# Unity: Animator cannot preview transition

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a 2d game in Unity and I have a treasure chest, when the player gets near an animation is triggered. In the chest animator I use an empty state as the default state which makes a transition to the OpenChest animation.

However, when I click on the transition arrow, under settings it says "cannot preview transition: source state does not have motion". Is there a way to preview the transition graph?

Answer (score 0):

Its a little late now... 
but try using a 1 frame animation state of the closed chest instead of an empty state as the default state.